# New Tektro Novela Disc Brakes

Tags: mountain-bike, disc-brake

So two days ago I bought a brand new Carrera Sulcata MB. Ever since it came out of the shop the rear brake rubs constantly, but only on one side of the caliper. I've tried realigning by loosening, holding brake and then tightening, but to no avail. I also tried holding the rotor/calipers in a position where they don't rub, but as soon as I tighten the allen key bolt it goes back to rubbing. It doesn't rub when it's not tightened fully but I'm not sure that's very safe. Now they have started to squeak at a certain point of the rotation (very loud) - do I just have to let them bed in or is there anything I can do beforehand? It's quite frustrating.

Thanks!

Comment: Take the bike to the shop you bought it from and get them to adjust the brakes. Most shops will give you a free six-week service on a new bike

Comment: Do try bedding in the brake pads before you return to the shop for your tweak... that's 30 "full speed" to "stopped" braking events without skidding the rear tyre.

Comment: Many years ago I had Novela's on a bike, nothing I did could stop the rubbing apart from upgrading. That was getting on to 10 years ago so hopefully they've improved some especially since they're still OEM spec'd on so many entry level bikes!

Comment: Mike - this question is now five months old.  What happened?  Are your brakes still rubbing ?

Answer (score 1):

The brakes are mechanical brakes. Normally (I don't know this brand) the brake lever moves one side of the pads only and pushes the disc against the other. When properly adjusted the disc moves very slightly into the non-moveable pad.

Normally the pad that move is the outboard pad, and the fixed one is the inside pad. To adjust you probably need to unwind the inside pad 1/4 or 1/2 turn, and maybe readjust the calipers.

Refer [Here](http://www.artscyclery.com/learningcenter/mechanicaldiscbrakesetup.html) for some good instructions.

Answer (score 0):

With mechanical discs the force from flexed brake housing can often make adjusting caliper position difficult.  Try disconnecting the cable and housing, then adjusting the caliper position by dialing in the pads until the disc is pinched then locking down the caliper fixing bolts.  Next you will need to  dial back the pad adjustment screws and reconnecting the cable and housing.

The process is involved but once you get the hang of it it seems to work great at getting stubborn calipers into alignment.